# Execute script after loading server side rendered React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have a server rendered react component, which I am trying to add a chart to. The way it works is that you have to have a canvas, and then execute something like:

```
var context = document.getElementById('chartId').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
```

For that to work, I have to execute this code on the client side because of the DOM interaction. Using `componentDidMount` won't work either since it doesn't get called on server rendered components.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-render the component again on clientside something like this:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        React.render(<RequestView /> ,
            document.getElementById('reactmount')
        );
    }
}
```

with

```
componentDidMount: function(){
     if(window){
          var context = document.getElementById('chartId').getContext('2d');
          var chart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
     }
},
```

Comment: and where would this code go? if I could find something to add to the component jsx I would be happy, but I don't want to have to add this elsewhere because I might have many of these components around

Comment: You should add your components as script tags, so they will be rendered client-side. Otherwise I don't understand why you are using react if you only render components to strings. You can have a look at this example [link](https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example).

Comment: Thanks for the link. The problem is that this example have only one view. Once you have more views, it would be complicated to maintain: one react component, one html and one reloadReact.js for each view as the example proposes. Also, I would prefer if I could use [react router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router).